# What can I do in this case?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

When I integrated the HMS Core SDK into my game. However, the game
was rejected during app review due to the following reason: On a mobile phone
where the latest version of HMS Core (APK) was not installed, a pop-up is
displayed during game launch, indicating that HMS Core (APK) needs to be
installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate and rectify the fault first. If HMS Core (APK) cannot be uninstalled or no update pop-up is displayed during fault locating, use a non-Huawei mobile phone to perform the test, and locate the fault based on the logs. Please upload your log file so I can help you further.